# iPhone, background service screen capture

Tags: ios, objective-c

**Use-case:**

1. An app/service is running in the background
2. Another arbitrary 3rd party app is running in the foreground
3. The background app/service defined @ #1 is taking Screenshots and sends them through TCP

---

Is the above use-case supported by iOS? can a background ~service~ run and take screen shots in this aspect?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like that would have serious security implications, which probably means it can't be done. I probably wouldn't be happy about something taking screenshots of my e-banking app. And there is no such thing as a background service on iOS, at least not for anybody other than Apple.

Comment: Right, however, IF, the background app is notionally used to lunch the 3rd party app ( when it goes to background ) then this might make scene...

Comment: Check [this link][1] out, I think this is what you are looking for 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23709852/about-airplay-mirroring-things-after-fp-setup